# Mac Mountain Lion Error - "isn't in fPermittedFrontASNs"

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, launchd, py2app

I have a python script that has been converted to a bundled application using py2app.  When invoked manually, it runs fine.  However, under Mountain Lion, when I try to invoke it using launchd, I get the following error in the system log:

> Aug  8 07:15:02 StraylightPro.local Irrigate[79689]: Irrigate Error
>   Aug  8 07:15:02 StraylightPro.local coreservicesd[77]: Application
>   App:"Irrigate" [ 0x0/0x697596f]  @ 0x0x7fe77240cec0 tried to be
>   brought forward, but isn't in fPermittedFrontASNs ( (
>   ASN:0x0-0x1cb2cb1:) ), so denying.

It seems pretty clear that this is the result of the new security features in Mountain Lion, but searching through Apple's Developer docs and Googling around on the web for the term "fPermittedFrontASNs" hasn't turned up anything.

It would be really nice if I could add an extended attribute to the application bundle or add a line to the launchd plist file that would solve this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that it is a Security Restriction posed by Gatekeeper, you can deactivate Gatekeeper for testing purposes with:

> spctl --master-disable

If it works, you can add an appropriate rule with the spctl command. Look at 'man spctl' for instructions.

Comment: Even with GateKeeper disabled, this happens to me as well when installing SugarSync.

Answer (score 0):

Is the application signed?

According to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/62707/how-to-get-installers-not-to-hang-on-waiting-for-other-installations-to-complet, which refers to [a page on Apple's support site](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5290?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US), applications signed with an Developer ID won't launch when the application bundle is changed.

Applications created with the current version of py2app can change after first launch because some files aren't byte-compiled when creating the app bundle and will be compiled at first launch. That's a bug that I'll fix in a future update.